# How to know when all content is loaded on the page from AJAX call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, loading

Hopefully someone can help me out here.

In my application I am making some quite large AJAX calls, getting HTML to drop into my page. This HTML could contain up to 7 or 8 images.

I am currently using AJAX like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'ajax-content/page.html'
}).done(function(data) {

    $('#case_study').html('<div class="loading"></div>');

    $('#case_study').append(data);

    // EVERYTHING AFTER THIS POINT SHOULD ONLY RUN ONCE ALL CONTENT IS
    // SUCCESSFULLY LOADED ON THE PAGE

    $('#case_study').css("max-height", "3000px");

    $('.loading').remove();

}).fail(function(data) {

    console.log("FAIL");
    console.log(data);

});
```

Now this all works fine, but, the code in `.done` runs as soon as the server has responded with my HTML, this is great, but not exactly what I am looking for.

What I need to know is, after I have run `$('#case_study').append(data)` when is all of the content actually visible to the user, when have all the images finished loading etc.

If anyone can help me work out how to do this that would be fantastic.

Cheers.

Comment: Add an eventlistener to the images.

Comment: @putvande would you be able to provide an example please? I'm not sure I fully understand.

Comment: Not quite sure why this deserves a downvote either. Can whoever downvoted please tell me why so I can fix the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are only waiting for the images you could add an eventListener to the images and wait for them all the finished loading:

```
var index = 0;
$('img').on('load', function() {
    index++;
    if (index == $('img').length - 1) {
        // show your content
    }
});
```

Comment: Ah i see, thanks for this, it works great! My understanding is that images are what take longest to load, is this the best thing to wait for, or is there a way of knowing when everything inside of a containing element is loaded?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the load function of jQuery?

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'ajax-content/page.html'
}).done(function(data) {

    $('#case_study').html('<div class="loading"></div>');

    $('#case_study').append(data).load(function() {
      $('#case_study').css("max-height", "3000px");

      $('.loading').remove();
    });

}).fail(function(data) {

    console.log("FAIL");
    console.log(data);

});
```

Comment: I have not tried this no. Does the `.load` function only run when all content within `#case_study` is loaded, including all images and all other content? -- After testing I don't think this works, in the following code my `console.log()` never fires: `$('#case_study').append(data).load(function(){console.log("all content loaded");});`

Comment: _The load event is sent to an element when it and all sub-elements have been completely loaded._ See also [link]https://api.jquery.com/load-event/, but it seems deprecated, so better use .on('load', function...

Comment: I see thanks, unfortunately the code is still not working. I have tried a few different options but I cannot get my `console.log()` to trigger.